# How do you define a BigQuery schema with empty json objects parsed as string?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I can't figure out how to define a BigQuery schema that supports empty JSON objects. How can I define a schema that supports importing data with this (annoying) dynamic JSON object?

Data -

```
{"X":"Chrome","Y":12,"Z":{}}
{"X":"Chrome","Y":12,"Z":{"X":""}}
{"X":"Chrome","Y":12,"Z":{"X":"","Y":""}}
```

Schema -

```
[
  {
    "name": "X",
    "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Y",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Z",
    "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: JSON object specified for non-record field: Z

Comment: Perhaps the error may be due to the fact that your "Z" type is declared as a "STRING" type, while it actually holds an object? For nesting, you can try to change it into an ARRAY type, and put the "Z" object into the array as a single element. See official documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated

Comment: I could add a step before the ingestion to stringy the object, but I was hoping that this problem was common enough that they'd have a way to handle the string conversion on their side.